# Is my ceiling box sufficiently grounded?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, grounding

I just installed a new (ceiling fan rated) metal ceiling box (something like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Westinghouse-21-5-cu-in-Retrofit-Ceiling-Fan-Saf-T-Brace-0140000/204845573)) and a new ceiling fan. After completing everything, I just remembered that I forgot to explicitly ground the ceiling box. However, the ceiling fan mounting bracket (looks something like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Merwry-Matte-Black-Mounting-Bracket-13431102700101/206438711)) *is* grounded. The ceiling fan mounting bracket is screwed into the ceiling box.

**Since the mounting bracket is grounded and it is screwed into the ceiling box, is my ceiling box sufficiently grounded?** Or should I take the fan down and go back up there to explicitly ground the ceiling box? Thanks!

Comment: It might be grounded, but paint is insulating somewhat.  The screws should bite into bare metal and make ground, but without seeing the screw holes it is hard to be sure.

Comment: I also think that it is code(need expert) that any boxes need to be grounded themselves and not depend on fixtures or other means of grounding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the ground wire from your feed and connect it to the fan box with a 10-32 grounding screw. You can then connect the green wire from your fan bracket to the end of the ground wire you just wraped around the grounding screw. There's probably a ground wire coming out of the fan too that has to be connected. If you are using EMT conduit into the box and it is grounded, then the box is grounded from the conduit.

You need to go back and do this right.